# is there a function list plugin for notepad++ 6.2.3

Tags: plugins, notepad++

Is there a function list plugin for Notepad++ 6.2.3?

I had used TagsView plugin and function list plugin in Npp 5.8, the plugin sometimes losts some functions which I defined. And when opening the TagsView sidebar, it always display `VARIABLE` first which I don't want to show. I found that function list plugin does not fit for Npp 6.2.3.

Has anyone modified the function list plugin (or any other plugin) to fit 6.2.3?

Answer (score 14):

I use sourcecookifier and it looks good, except not show vailable list for perl :-(

http://sourceforge.net/projects/sourcecookifier/

Comment: This plugin works well for `java` with **Notepad++ 6.3.3**

Comment: I think this should be marked as the answer

Answer (score 11):

The Function List plug-in for Notepad++ must be installed manually.

Using FunctionList plug-in v2.1 with Notepad++ v5.9 and above, the installation steps are as follows:

1. Download the Function List plug-in from http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/
2. Unzip the FunctionList plug-in and copy the files as follows:

   - **FunctionList.dll**copied to

     - XP, Vista or Win7 32-bit: C:\Program Files\Notepad++\plugins
     - Vista or Win7 64-bit: C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins
   - **C++.flb** and **Gmod Lua.bmp**copied to

     - XP, Vista or Win7 32-bit: C:\Program Files\Notepad++\plugins\Config
     - Vista or Win7 64-bit: C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins\Config
   - **FunctionListRules.xml**copied to:

     - XP: C:\Documents and Settings\[UserName]\Application Data\Notepad++\plugins\config
     - Vista or Win7: C:\Users\[UserName]\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\plugins\config
     - Note:  The install.txt says to use your %APPDATA% path.  Your %APPDATA% path can easily be found by typing %APPDATA% into your Windows Start->Run or Start->Start Search box.
3. Start Notepad++, the **Function List** plug-in menu should now appear in Menu: **Plugins** –> **Function List**

[**Please click here for more details**](http://chrisjakeway.wordpress.com/2009/10/26/install-functionlist-plug-in-for-notepad/)

Comment: Functionlist hasn't been updated in years. Right now, it is highly unstable so i can't recommend it.

Comment: It doesn't show any method of `java` class!

Comment: @AnandVeeramani, What's with Notepad++, wanting us to do so many actions just to install a simple plugin.